# python pandas - dynamic cleaning of 4000 csvs with varying column/rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm looking for a way to clean 4000 csvs of similar format but with varying number of rows/columns and then combine them into a single table (possibly SQLite as over 4 million records). The data is related origin/destination (O/D) surveys - with each csv being a specfic route and ticket type that contains multiple stop to stop counts (e.g. route 101 Adult, route 101 child wkend, etc., etc.). Each csv is in a stepped format similar to, where the csv has the same number of rows (if excluding first row (route info)) as it does columns:

```
route info
stop1, stop1
stop2, value, stop2
stop3, value, value, stop3
stop4, value, value, value, stop4
```

OR

```
route info
stop11, stop11
stop32, value, stop32
....
stop150, value, value, value, ......., stop150
```

[Sample raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvMy0.png)

However, each csv can have different/more/less O/D combinations. The data has no headers making it difficult to get into my proposed "intermediary step".

[Intermediary cleaning step - not required if can go directly to final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM5DG.png)

[Required cleaned output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Ur2.png)

I've only begun looking into a solution but encountering issues with loading data into a Pandas DataFrame:

- *CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3*. (corrected by using sep = "\t")
- all data seen in single column (correct by opening data with csv.reader first to get number of columns and assigning each a number)

```
    for dirty_csv in csvs_to_be_cleaned:
        print (dirty_csv)
        # open csv to get number of columns so that Pandas can read data
        with open(dirty_csv, 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            # subtract 1 from length to get actual number of columns
            # first row contains route/ticket info (which will be populated in 2 new fields)
            col_range = len(list(reader)) - 1
        default_cols = [str(i) for i in range(col_range)] # create some col names
        df = pd.read_csv(dirty_csv, sep = "\t", delimiter=",", names = default_cols, header = None)
        print(df)
```

**Questions**:

- Is there a more elegant solution to get Pandas to see all data in csv where data/header is present in stepped fashion
- Can Pandas use the first string entry in a column as column header?

I'm wondering if there is a similar solution out there or someone willing to provide assistance.

python modules/process:

1. glob to get all csvs to be cleaned
2. process each csv individual using csv/pandas (full solution not written atm)
3. output cleaned csv to new folder
4. merge all into single SQLite table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to re-format the Origin/Destination file.  First, create a sample data set.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''
route r1
dest 1, Origin 1
dest 2,        a, Origin 2
dest 3,        b,        d, Origin 3
dest 4,        c,        e,        f, Origin 4
'''
```

Second, parse the file.

```
with StringIO(data) as handle:
    # get the route (first non-blank line)
    while True:
        line = next(handle).rstrip('\n')
        if line:
            break
    route = line
    
    origins = list()
    bus_trips = list()
    
    for line in handle:
        fields = line.rstrip().split(',')
        fields = [f.strip() for f in fields]
        
        destination = fields[0]
        origins.append(fields[-1])
        
        for origin, count in zip(origins[:-1], fields[1:]):
            t = (route, origin, destination, count)
            bus_trips.append(t)
```

`bus_trips` is a list of tuples.  You can convert it to a pandas data frame, and the use the pandas `.to_sql()` method to write to a database.

```
[('route r1', 'Origin 1', 'dest 2', 'a'),
 ('route r1', 'Origin 1', 'dest 3', 'b'),
 ('route r1', 'Origin 2', 'dest 3', 'd'),
 ('route r1', 'Origin 1', 'dest 4', 'c'),
 ('route r1', 'Origin 2', 'dest 4', 'e'),
 ('route r1', 'Origin 3', 'dest 4', 'f')]
```

Now, creating the data frame is straightforward, because we changed 'stair-step' format to rectangular format.

```
col_names = ['route', 'origin', 'destination', 'ride_count']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(bus_trips, columns=col_names)
print(df)

      route    origin destination ride_count
0  route r1  Origin 1      dest 2          a
1  route r1  Origin 1      dest 3          b
2  route r1  Origin 2      dest 3          d
3  route r1  Origin 1      dest 4          c
4  route r1  Origin 2      dest 4          e
5  route r1  Origin 3      dest 4          f
```

Comment: thank you very much @jsmart. A very nice solution - I was in rush to get data into a DF and do magic there but in hindsight is not needed. The use of ```fields[0]``` and ```fields[-1]``` is great. I was going to generate a func to get last row index that is not NaN - ```if x.last_valid_index() is None:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x[x.last_valid_index()].strip() ```

Comment: Great!  My approach is also to get to pandas as fast as possible, but sometimes we need pre-processing.  FYI: `json_normalize()` a good pandas function, for nested JSON https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html